# PHP Preg Replace to remove part of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I Want to remove a part from string using preg_replace, i searched for long but i couldn't find a way to help me make the correct expression.
the string:

```
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test     test test test test test test test test test test
<div>[[{"fid":"1915134","view_mode":"default","type":"media","attributes": {"height":360,"width":480,"alt":"#some text here","class":"media-element file-default"}}]]</div>
test test test test test test test test test test test test test testtest test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test
```

Remove the part start with `[[{"fid":"` and end with `}}]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$a = preg_replace('/\[\[{"fid"[^}\]]+}}\]\]/','',$a);
```